# Android read file from url

Tags: android

I created android application to stream online radio stations but it doesn't work.I want to read ip address from url and assign it to string and when user selects radio to listen I should add port to that string!!!

```
    public class BackgroundService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener
{
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private String STREAM_URL;
    final String textSource = "http://audiophileradio.stream/Ip.txt";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        new MyTask().execute();

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String radio = sharedPreferences.getString("station", "8000");

        if (radio != null && radio.equals("8000"))
        {
            STREAM_URL = "http://178.149.88.126:8000/";
        }
        if (radio != null && radio.equals("8010"))
        {
            STREAM_URL = "http://178.149.88.126:8010/";
        }
        if (radio != null && radio.equals("8020"))
        {
            STREAM_URL = "http://178.149.88.126:8020/";
        }
        if (radio != null && radio.equals("8030"))
        {
            STREAM_URL = "http://178.149.88.126:8030/";
        }

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try
        {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(STREAM_URL);
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            try
            {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(STREAM_URL);
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
                    {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer) {
        stopSelf();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent)
    {
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        String textResult;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            URL textUrl;

            try {
                textUrl = new URL(textSource);

                BufferedReader bufferReader
                        = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(textUrl.openStream()));

                String StringBuffer;
                String stringText = "";
                while ((StringBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringText += StringBuffer;
                }
                bufferReader.close();

                textResult = stringText;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                textResult = e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                textResult = e.toString();
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            Log.d("DebugTag", "Value2: " + textResult);

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
}
05-12 10:35:48.625 17340-17340/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.

05-12 10:35:48.625 17340-17340/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority [1], There is no sepolicy version file.

05-12 10:35:48.625 17340-17340/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority , priority version is VE=SEPF_GT-I9301I_4.4.2_0055


05-12 10:35:48.625 17340-17340/? I/SELinux: selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /seapp_contexts
05-12 10:35:48.625 17340-17340/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
05-12 10:35:48.835 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window.setStatusBarColor, referenced from method audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio.MainActivity.onCreate
05-12 10:35:48.835 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 21917: Landroid/view/Window;.setStatusBarColor (I)V
05-12 10:35:48.835 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0081
05-12 10:35:48.865 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
05-12 10:35:48.865 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 21896: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;I)V
05-12 10:35:48.865 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
05-12 10:35:48.875 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
05-12 10:35:48.875 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
05-12 10:35:48.875 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 21898: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
05-12 10:35:48.875 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
05-12 10:35:48.875 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
05-12 10:35:48.875 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 21902: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
05-12 10:35:48.875 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
05-12 10:35:48.875 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
05-12 10:35:48.875 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 505: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
05-12 10:35:48.875 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
05-12 10:35:48.875 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
05-12 10:35:48.875 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 527: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
05-12 10:35:48.875 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
05-12 10:35:48.965 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList
05-12 10:35:48.965 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 316: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
05-12 10:35:48.965 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
05-12 10:35:49.175 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
05-12 10:35:49.175 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 468: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
05-12 10:35:49.175 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
05-12 10:35:49.175 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
05-12 10:35:49.175 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 470: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
05-12 10:35:49.175 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
05-12 10:35:49.185 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
05-12 10:35:49.185 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 150 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper;
05-12 10:35:49.185 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x000c
05-12 10:35:49.315 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/ProgressBar: setProgressDrawable drawableHeight = 24
05-12 10:35:49.335 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/AbsSeekBar: AbsSeekBar Constructor: misSeebarAnimationAvailable = false
05-12 10:35:49.345 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/ProgressBar: setProgressDrawable drawableHeight = 24
05-12 10:35:49.345 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/ProgressBar: setProgressDrawable getHeight() = 0
05-12 10:35:49.345 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/ProgressBar: updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
05-12 10:35:49.345 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/ProgressBar: updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
05-12 10:35:49.345 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/ProgressBar: updateDrawableBounds: right = -64
05-12 10:35:49.345 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/ProgressBar: updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 0
05-12 10:35:49.345 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/ProgressBar: updateDrawableBounds: mProgressDrawable.setBounds()
05-12 10:35:49.365 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio V/MediaPlayer-JNI: native_setup
05-12 10:35:49.365 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio V/MediaPlayer: constructor
05-12 10:35:49.365 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio V/MediaPlayer: setListener
05-12 10:35:49.365 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
05-12 10:35:49.405 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio V/MediaPlayer-JNI: native_setup
05-12 10:35:49.405 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio V/MediaPlayer: constructor
05-12 10:35:49.405 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio V/MediaPlayer: setListener
05-12 10:35:49.405 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
05-12 10:35:49.415 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/app/Notification;.headsUpContentView
05-12 10:35:49.415 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instance field 14
05-12 10:35:49.415 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x5b at 0x005d
05-12 10:35:49.415 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/app/Notification;.headsUpContentView
05-12 10:35:49.415 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instance field 14
05-12 10:35:49.415 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x5b at 0x004c
05-12 10:35:49.415 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/app/Notification;.headsUpContentView
05-12 10:35:49.415 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x000e at 0x54 in Landroid/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat;.addHeadsUpToBuilderLollipop
05-12 10:35:49.415 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/app/Notification;.headsUpContentView
05-12 10:35:49.415 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x000e at 0x61 in Landroid/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat;.addHeadsUpToBuilderLollipop
05-12 10:35:49.485 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
                                                                                         OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.07
                                                                                         Build Date: 01/27/14 Mon
                                                                                         Local Branch: base_au149_adreno_au169_patches
                                                                                         Remote Branch: 
                                                                                         Local Patches: 
                                                                                         Reconstruct Branch: 
05-12 10:35:49.605 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
05-12 10:35:49.615 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/ProgressBar: updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
05-12 10:35:49.615 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/ProgressBar: updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
05-12 10:35:49.615 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/ProgressBar: updateDrawableBounds: right = 568
05-12 10:35:49.615 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/ProgressBar: updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 68
05-12 10:35:49.615 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/ProgressBar: updateDrawableBounds: mProgressDrawable.setBounds()
05-12 10:35:49.625 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat.drawableHotspotChanged, referenced from method android.support.design.internal.ForegroundLinearLayout.drawableHotspotChanged
05-12 10:35:49.625 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 18400: Landroid/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutCompat;.drawableHotspotChanged (FF)V
05-12 10:35:49.625 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
05-12 10:36:19.895 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio E/Play: onPlay
05-12 10:36:19.955 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio V/MediaPlayer-JNI: native_setup
05-12 10:36:19.955 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio V/MediaPlayer: constructor
05-12 10:36:19.965 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio V/MediaPlayer: setListener
05-12 10:36:19.965 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
05-12 10:36:20.005 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio E/MediaPlayer: Unable to create media player
05-12 10:36:20.005 17340-17352/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=8, ext1=0, ext2=0
05-12 10:36:20.005 17340-17352/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio V/MediaPlayer: notify(8, 0, 0) callback on disconnected mediaplayer
05-12 10:36:20.015 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err: java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
05-12 10:36:20.015 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
05-12 10:36:20.015 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1317)
05-12 10:36:20.015 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1240)
05-12 10:36:20.015 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio.BackgroundService.onCreate(BackgroundService.java:107)
05-12 10:36:20.015 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2736)
05-12 10:36:20.015 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:169)
05-12 10:36:20.015 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
05-12 10:36:20.015 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-12 10:36:20.015 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-12 10:36:20.015 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
05-12 10:36:20.015 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 10:36:20.015 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-12 10:36:20.015 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
05-12 10:36:20.015 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
05-12 10:36:20.015 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
05-12 10:36:20.015 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-12 10:36:20.015 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio V/MediaPlayer: isPlaying: no active player
05-12 10:36:20.015 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 0
05-12 10:36:20.015 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio V/MediaPlayer-JNI: reset
05-12 10:36:20.015 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio V/MediaPlayer: reset
05-12 10:36:20.015 17340-17352/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=8, ext1=0, ext2=0
05-12 10:36:20.015 17340-17352/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio V/MediaPlayer: notify(8, 0, 0) callback on disconnected mediaplayer
05-12 10:36:20.015 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio E/MediaPlayer: Unable to create media player
05-12 10:36:20.015 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err: java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
05-12 10:36:20.025 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
05-12 10:36:20.025 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1317)
05-12 10:36:20.025 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1240)
05-12 10:36:20.025 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio.BackgroundService.onStartCommand(BackgroundService.java:124)
05-12 10:36:20.025 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2883)
05-12 10:36:20.025 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:169)
05-12 10:36:20.025 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374)
05-12 10:36:20.025 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-12 10:36:20.025 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-12 10:36:20.025 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
05-12 10:36:20.025 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 10:36:20.025 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-12 10:36:20.025 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
05-12 10:36:20.025 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
05-12 10:36:20.035 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
05-12 10:36:20.035 17340-17340/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-12 10:36:20.195 17340-19228/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio I/System.out: Thread-66912(HTTPLog):isShipBuild true
05-12 10:36:20.195 17340-19228/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio I/System.out: Thread-66912(HTTPLog):SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
05-12 10:36:20.425 17340-19228/audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio D/MyTag: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Comment: Well what does happen instead? Should we guess?

Comment: When I press play button to start radio nothing happens!!!

Comment: Insufficient info of course. Which code lines are executed? Which not?. Post the logcat please.

Comment: Well which problem do you see in that logcat?

Comment: You know you are starting the media player before your thread has finished?

Comment: java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.

Comment: And what would be the data source?

Comment: The ip address that I should get from the url

Comment: Add log statements so you see which STREAM_URL is used. And see that it is wrong as the thread has not finished yet.

Comment: I used toast.It displays empty message!

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: I see no toast.

Comment: I added Toast.makeText(this,STREAM_URL,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); inside if (radio != null && radio.equals("8000"))

Comment: Yes it is empty. That is what i said. You are toasting and starting the media player before the thread is finished. Its a thread! You have just started the thread! It takes a time before it is finished. But meanwhile you are already toasting and starting the mediaplayer. Use more Log statements to see the sequence.

Comment: How to start mediaplayer after finishing thread ?

Comment: Well what is the problem doing so? Only start it if ip is known. Not sooner.

Comment: Like this: if(!text.toString().isEmpty())
            {
                STREAM_URL = text.toString();
                Toast.makeText(this, STREAM_URL, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } ???

Comment: Well tell us. Does that work? (I know the answer).

Comment: No it doesn't!!!

Comment: Please indicate in your code the line where the ip is known. You should remove all code after thread.start() from onCreate and put it in its own function. Please put the logcat in a different code block as your code.

Comment: `conn.setConnectTimeout(60000);`?? A minute??

Comment: How long should it be?

Comment: Remove that line. But then it depends on your situation. Lets concentrate on the design.

Comment: What should I do now?

Comment: That i already told you!

Comment: I added inside try block STREAM_URL = text.toString();
                    Toast.makeText(this, STREAM_URL, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); and I get cannot resolve method makeText()

Comment: You are not allowed to use Toast() statements in the run() of a Thread. Use Log statements instead. I asked you that before. But instead of adding all kinds of stuff you better do what i asked you to do. As otherwise this takes much too much time.

Comment: When I use Log.d("DebugTag", "Value: " + STREAM_URL); inside try block I get Value: 178.149.88.126:8000

Comment: Yes. Of course. So now do the things i asked you to do.

Comment: In what function should I put code after thread.start() and where is should I call that function?

Comment: You can just do what i asked first. After that you can come with new questions.

Comment: What you asked first?

Comment: `You should remove all code after thread.start() from onCreate and put it in its own function. Please put the logcat in a different code block as your code.`  Is is that difficult to read? `Please indicate in your code the line where the ip is known. `

Comment: I updated code inside question.I put code after thread.start() inside function!

Comment: `Please put the logcat in a different code block as your code.  Please indicate in your code the line where the ip is known.`. You did not do those two things. Why not?

Comment: Program crashes because of null pointer exception!

Comment: You still have not done what i asked you to do.

Comment: What do you mean by" Please put the logcat in a different code block as your code."

Comment: There is only one grey code block now. Isnt it? We wanna see two.

Comment: What is "grey" code block ?

Comment: I put log inside onStartCommand

Comment: You should do what i asked you to do instead.

Comment: Do you mean to put Log.d("DebugTag", "Value1: " + STREAM_URL); inside public void run function ?

Comment: You can do that. That is a good idea. But it is not what i asked you to do.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by put log in different code block?

Comment: Can you explain me that?

Comment: Following post has two -grey- code blocks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43942723/how-to-hold-button-

Comment: Which code is "gray" block code in my post?

Comment: Can you please write that you told me to do?

Answer (score 0):

Can use OkHttp :

Add this code in Gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0'
```

Use :

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
request = new Request.Builder().url("http://audiophileradio.stream/Ip.txt")
                     .addHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken)
                     .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                     .build();
response = getClient().newCall(request).execute();

InputStream in = response.body().byteStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String result, line = reader.readLine();
result = line;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    result += line;
}
System.out.println(result);
response.body().close();
```

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol request,response,csrftoken,getClient()

Comment: You must insert into gradle file and sync `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0'`