# How to hold Button reference in singleton class without memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, singleton

I have a singleton 'util' class. This class is doing a lot of operation with UI elements (with some custom button, edittext etc.), so it's quite uncomfortable to pass all of the ui object's reference every time I use the util class.
So I created a 'setup' method, like

```
    public void setStatusButtons (Button button1, Button button2, etc... ) {
    this.mButton1 = button1;
    this.mButton2 = button2;
    etc...
}
```

Then if I want to use them just use the mButton1, mButton2 ... fields.

But there is a problem with this solution. It can cause a memory-leak.
Is enough to create a 'free' method (and call it in onDestroy() or something like that), like:

```
 public void freeObjects () {
    this.mButton1 = null;
    this.mButton2 = null;
    etc...
}
```

or it's a very horrible and hacky solution and there is some nicer ? :)

In the util class now I have 15 methods (and this number can be more at the end of the project), so I really don't want to pass every time the UI object's reference, if I don't have to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> or it's a very horrible and hacky solution and there is some nicer

Get rid of the singleton. Then:

- Use inheritance, with your activities/fragments extending some base class that has your utility code
- Or, use composition, where your activities/fragments create an instance of your class with your utility code, rather than having a single global memory-leaking instance

Comment: Thank you. What do you think, can be WeakReference an alternative (third) solution?

Comment: @wyzard: That should get you fired, when your code is reviewed. There are certainly valid use cases for `WeakReference`. This is not one of them.